# beta regression and AIC (model selection)

Tags: r

I have a problem with Beta regression in R. I need to choose a model using a process similar to `stepAIC`. I am using `stepGAIC` from the `gamlss` package. I get this error message afetr running this code:

```
model <- betareg(proportion_of_completed_surveys ~ questions + readibility_lexile_survey_questions_expl, data = conference_surveys)

stepGAIC.CH(model,direction="backward", additive=TRUE)

Error in match.arg(model) : 'arg' should be one of “mean”, “precision”
```

Any solution would be much appreciated.

Peter

Comment: A side advice: Stepwise regression is a very unstable and dangerous procedure that could lead to wrong results.

Comment: `?stepGAIC` indicates that this procedure only accepts `gamlss` objects. What makes you think that a model with class `betareg` will work in `stepGAIC`? Incidentally, it looks like `gamlss()` has support for the beta distribution.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, so I wrote a function that could help you.

Try this:

```
install_github("SergioGarofalo/StepBeta") 
library(StepBeta)
modelStepAIC <- StepBeta(model, k = 2)
summary(modelStepAIC)
```

I hope this could be useful,

Sergio